# LightDM freezes at first startup

Tags: login, lightdm

Nearly every time I bootup my Ubuntu I come to the login screen. But instead of showing me the wallpaper from selected account, I just see the default purple background with those white dots on it. Anyway, at this screen I'm neither able to login (the text field does not accept input) nor to shut down, because I am unable to click the icon in the upper left (although I can move the mouse).

To work arond this problem, I switch to a TTY using <kbd>STRG</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, login and reboot using `sudo reboot`. After a restart, I can log in normally, the login screen will appear with my account's wallpaper. Also installing GDM didn't solve this issue.

I really tried a lot. I have this problem for about 2 months now and I've reinstalled Ubuntu 2 times during this period. I've also tried 12.10 and have the same issue there.

My hard drive is a WD Carviar black and I use an Asus Motherboard with an AMD CPU.

Answer (score 1):

It appears this issues was caused by my logitech Webcam.
The Bug is described here and should be solved soon.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1018020

I just detached my Webcam and hope it is solved for good.

---

I am not able to change it to "solved". Hope someone will do it, I can not find the button.